# Replacing two-gang manual switch to smart switch (AU)

Tags: electrical, wiring, smart-switch

I live in Australia and am trying replace a two-gang manual switch with a smart switch.

I found the neutral (black wire with red circle) and when connecting the red wire (next to it) to the Live In of the switch, the smart switch turns on.

I’m not sure how I should proceed from there? Should the black and red go in both Live Out connections? The colors are a bit confusing…

[image]

Answer (score 3):

### Wires aren't what you need just because you need them

Here's the problem. Your two lights are wired as two *switch loops*.

One cable contains supply live and switched live for lamp 1.  The other contains supply live and switched live for lamp 2.

Neutral is not among them, so you have no way to power your smart switch.

This smart switch is designed to be used in new construction, where a switch loop is not used: power is brought first to the switch box, then sent to the two lamps, with 3 total cables in the box.    It is not designed for nor compatible with switches where either one is wired as a *switch loop*.

You will need to significantly rework the in-wall wiring to support any switch which needs neutral.  At the least, one switch-to-light cable will need to be replaced with 3-core cable, or 2-core cable brought from a 3rd location with power.

Comment: Thanks, that’s very helpful. 

I guess no replacing the manual switch in that case… (by the way, the smart switch is powered on the way I have it connected currently)

Comment: @Ruben: The smart switch may well power on - but it's getting its power from the "loop" that goes through the lightbulb. So the light will always be "on" a little bit (though it may be so dim it's not possible to tell), and the smart switch has no way to turn the light either fully "off" or fully "on" :( .